# How to solve problem redirect to homepage without login

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

**Problem :**

i have problem when i open the apps it display login only for 2 seconds and it redirect to homepage without login. i need to logout first, then insert username and password to go to homepage.

**how can i solve that.**

**Expected :**

when open the apps it shows login page without redirect to homepage without login.

```
Open apps -> shows login page -> login by username & password -> homepage(if success)
```

i have try many ways such as set default page, `if else condition` when `initializeApps` but it is not worked.

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  rootPage:any = 'LoginPage';
  users = [];
  stafId:any;
  full_name :any;
  avatar:any;
  email:any;
  user_department:any;
  subscription: Subscription;
  //const LAST_RELOAD_KEY = 'lastAppReload';
  //mySubscription: any;


  constructor(
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private platform: Platform,
    private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private auth: AuthService,
    private menuCtrl: MenuController,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    public sqlite : SQLite,
    public data:DataService,
    private router:  Router,
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();


    this.platform.backButton.subscribe(async () => {
      navigator['app'].exitApp();   
});

  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();

    });
  }
```

**login.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private menuCtrl: MenuController,
    private auth: AuthService,
    public events: Events,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
  }

  /*createUser(user) {
  console.log('User created!')
  this.events.publish('user:created', user, Date.now());
}*/

  submit(form) {
    this.auth.login(form.value);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**login.html**

```
<ion-content class="bg-image">

  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo"><img src="/assets/imgs/logo2.png"></div>

  </div>

<div padding>
   <form class="content" #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(form)">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row color="primary" justify-content-center>
        <ion-col align-self-center size-md="10" size-lg="15" size-xs="11">
          <div class="login-detail">
            <ion-item class="username" color="transparent">
              <ion-input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Nama Pengguna" ngModel required></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item class="password" color="transparent">
              <ion-input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Kata Laluan" ngModel required></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <div padding>
              <button class="login" type="submit" expand="block">LOG MASUK</button>
            </div>

          </div>

        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>

      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </form>

</div>
<ion-content/>
```

app-routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {AuthGuard} from './guards/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { 
    path: 'login', 
    loadChildren: './authentication/login/login.module#LoginPageModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  { 
    path: 'profile', 
    loadChildren: './profile/profile.module#ProfilePageModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard] 
  },


];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: please show us the login html and .ts file

Comment: can you please update the file in stackblitz so we can sort this issue better

Comment: Please check the  url also it clearly explains https://blog.flicher.net/ionic-4-user-registration-login-tutorial/

Comment: @Utkarsh i hve show the codes

Comment: Please provide your route file code. Seems like issue with routing flow.

Comment: i hve insert app-routing @AnkurAkvaliya can you check it please?

Comment: You might have better luck getting an answer on here if you produce minimal repro code. Since you're using Angular, I would reproduce your code using StackBlitz so we can see everything that's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Using Route guards.

CanActivate: seems to solve your issue by current observation.

Please upload your files.

Comment: i have used the route guard. at first it works, but later after i work on other things it become like this

Answer (score 0):

Hello you have to check that how you manage login and logout status in your application 
like you should check that if you logged in you passing user_access_token or if you not logged in then you can pass visitor token 
then if you manage this way following wa you have to identify that user logged in or not
if user logged in then save user_access_token in one variable and check that conditions like

```
userLogin = localStorage.getItem('user_access_token') !== null;

  if (this.userLogin){
              /* path that you want to redirect
            } else if {
             /* path that you want to redirect in case logout
            }
```

that is one way there are many way to manage those stuff